# I'm getting an error while running java program in Visual studio code,what should I do?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm getting like this,
Error: Could not find or load main class Graphs.BFS
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Graphs.BFS

I want my system to run java codes as before.
Please someone help me to find the solution to this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.